# Passing parent data to a list or crud associated with a nested resource in backpack for laravel

Tags: laravel-backpack

I am using this tutorial https://backpackforlaravel.com/articles/tutorials/nested-resources-in-backpack-crud
to set up a nested resource in backpack.  I realize that I can customize the view  with

```
$this->crud->setListView('my-view-name');
```

but I am wondering how I can pass other data into this view.  I would like to pass the parent resource so that I can say something like

```
Posts for {{$parent_resource->title}}
```

at the top of the list(index) view.

So I guess I was wondering if there is any way to pass the parent resource model to the list and crud views?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to write things like `Posts for {{ $parent_resource->title }}`, but from the nested controller, NOT the view.

In Backpack 3.5 you can [change the heading & subheading of operations](https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/3.5/crud-operations#titles-headings-and-subheadings), using these methods:

```php
$this->crud->setTitle('some string', 'create'); // set the Title for the create action
$this->crud->setHeading('some string', 'create'); // set the Heading for the create action
$this->crud->setSubheading('some string', 'create'); // set the Subheading for the create action
```

Now, in `ChildCrudController::setup()` you have the request, so you could:

- get the parent id from `$this->crud->request`;
- get that particular parent entry from the db;
- use the methods above to set the text of the title (browser title bar), heading (biggest text on page) or subheading (second biggest text on page, right next to the heading);

Hope it helps. Cheers!